# Replace string with quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace strings having no quotes+HTML tag with those having quotes.

Example: `worlds` in `<i>worlds<i>` to be replaced with `World's`. So, `<i>worlds<i>` becomes World's.

I'm using the following code, but it doesn't take into account the `'`(quotes).

```
    preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote('worlds') . '\b/i', '<i>$0</i>', 'World's');
```

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the ' by placing \ before. Try this:

```
 preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote(worlds) . '\b/i', '<i>$0</i>', 'World\'s');
```